# Can run spring boot application from eclipse but not from terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, maven

I have a problem with a Spring boot project, it has another spring boot project as a dependency in its pom.xml.
I can run it properly using eclipse, but an error shows up when I try to run it with terminal using the command `mvn spring-boot:run`.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project platform-service: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.test.platform:platform-service:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.test:student-service:jar:exec:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

This is how I added the dependency in pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>student-service</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

I have tried different solutions like `mvn package spring-boot:repackage` but it didn't work.

Thank you so much.

Comment: You added com. **talan** :student-service but the app complains about com. **test** :student-service missing. Typo ?

Comment: @Benoit I fixed that, but still doesn't work

Comment: Can you post the `pom.xml` of the project you're trying to run in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Add this plugin after dependencies in **pom.xml**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Save this and run again.